# MySQL Timestamp - why all zeros?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, phpmyadmin

I'm using PHPMyAdmin and I've got a MySQL table column called "timestamp." The type (surprise!) is `TIMESTAMP`, and in 'attributes' I've set it to `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

However, each new record gets a timestamp that looks like this:

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

I have explicitly set the default value to none, but when I save and come back to look, it is set to all zeros as above.

The relevant PHP records page hits with this query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `pagehit` (user_id, pageurl)
VALUES ('" . $userid . "', '" . $pageurl . "')";
```

The whole thing is running under XAMPP.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What am I missing?

You don't update :)

Use `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` along with `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 10):

Try setting the default value to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead of putting that in the attributes.

[MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html)

Answer (score 3):

If your `timestamp` column captures only the insertion time then use only

```
timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Otherwise if it is for modification time then use like as follows

```
timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case works like this:

In phpMyAdmin:

```
ALTER TABLE `name_table`  ADD  `name_row` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

In PHP sintax for the row:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```