# Updating date by CURRENT_TIMESTAMP .. Why all Zeros?

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

I am trying to update date whenever any updates occur on the record, the field type is `datetime` and I set the default value to  `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. when update sql is excuted the result is all zeros!

`0000-00-00 00:00:00`

```
   $sql = 'INSERT INTO product_shop_offers (id,product_id,shop_id,price,currency_id,added_by,last_update)'
            . ' VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=?,shop_id=?,price=?,currency_id=?,added_by=?,last_update=?';

    $this->db->query($sql, array(
                $storeInfoArray['recordId'],
                $productId,
                $storeInfoArray['storeNameNo'],
                $storeInfoArray['price'],
                $storeInfoArray['currency'],
                $addedBy,
                'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()',   
                $storeInfoArray['recordId'],
                $storeInfoArray['storeNameNo'],
                $storeInfoArray['price'],
                $storeInfoArray['currency'],
                $addedBy,
                'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()'
            ))
```

Note: I checked [Similar problem question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837190/mysql-timestamp-why-all-zeros) but I didn't understand the problem!!can somebody help please.

Comment: Thanks everybody for help, I really gain new valuable information from you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it because you are binding in the string `'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()'`.. I'm not sure you can do that and it is being converted to zeros.

If you have the default set in the database, why bother binding it in at all? Just remove the field from the statement.. oh and you'll need to add the attribute `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to the column:

```
ALTER TABLE product_shop_offers
MODIFY COLUMN last_update DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

If you need it otherwise, you may have to write it into the query directly.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be helpful for you

> [MySQL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP field updates on every update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357341/mysql-current-timestamp-field-updates-on-every-update)

Answer (score 0):

Change `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` to `NOW()`

Another possible way is to set the field type from `datetime` to `timestamp`

Comment: MySQL can covert `timestamp` to `datetime` on insert.. it is a good suggestion, but not the cause of the issue.

Comment: hmm.. wait, your primary key is product_id not id?